# Equation Solving: Solution in terms of predefined functions

Tags: equation-solving

Is there a way that I can have Mathematica give me the solution of a problem it has solved in terms of functions that I have predefined?
The specific problem I'm trying to solve is:

```
s = alp^2 (E0*mu1 + N01);
k = 1 - E^(-Pmax/s^2) + Sqrt[π*Pmax]/(2*s)*Erfc[Sqrt[Pmax]/s];

E1 = s^2 (1 - E^(-Pmax/s^2));

epsd = E1 - (s*k)^2;

A = 1 + epsd/((k*alp)^2 N01);

c = E1/(N01*(k*alp)^2);

SIG1 = (E0*mu1)/N01; SIG2 = (E1*mu2)/N02;

D[1 - 2 E^(-((A SNRth)/SIG1)) Sqrt[(c SNRth)/(SIG1 SIG2)]
     BesselK[1, 2 Sqrt[(c SNRth)/(SIG1 SIG2)]], {alp}]
```

The solution given by *Mathematica* is extremely lengthy. However, by observation it can be seen that many of the functions that I have defined above the differentiation operator are contained within the solution.

Comment: E.g. `Simplify[x^3 + 3 x^2 - 2 x + 1, 
 f[x] == x^3 + 1 && g[x] == 3 x^2 - 2 x]` yields `f[x] + g[x]`. This can be adjusted to more specific cases. There are another ways to get expected results, but until no examples are given we won't be able to help more.

Comment: @DaveS: please add that to your question (edit), so that future users can directly see it. Thank you!

Comment: @Artes I'm sorry, I'm new to this forum. Is there a way I can directly copy Mathematica code into my question?

Comment: @DaveS Perhaps this post could be useful [Additional useful buttons for our M.SE editor](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor) but I've never used it.